# Tap Jacking protection for Flutter apps

Tags: flutter, dart

I have seen that there wont be any way of providing Tap jacking for flutter apps but I came across this
saying,
It is possible to globally disable all touches when obscured by setting this property on the root view in your MainActivity (Kotlin code Sample):

```
val view = findViewById<View>(android.R.id.content).rootView
view.filterTouchesWhenObscured = true
```

Any suggestions how to convert the above code in dart Language for Flutter App

Comment: add the reference links where guys do Tap jacking will figure out what's the solution.

Answer (score 0):

There's no solution for this yet by the flutter community.

Answer (score 0):

It's still an open issue on flutter's gh https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/40422